# Mathematica AppendTo a list in a function, which is handed the list

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to append a value to a list, which I am handing to the function such as :

```
p = {{"Blaaaa"}};
AppendTo[p, {"Lalala"}];
dran [h_] := AppendTo[h, {"Hahaha"}]
dran[p]
```

But I recieve the following error:

AppendTo: {{Blaaaa},{Lalala}} is not a variable with a value, so its value cannot be changed.

which I do not understand. I mean I am not changing any values.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I feel like this is really basic, but I really do not get it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of the error is that in mathematica by default function  args are effectively passed by copy and can not be modified.  `AppendTo` ( as with all mathematica intrinsics that end with `To` ) actually modifies its argument. Setting the `HoldFirst` attribute lets you modify the argument.

```
p = {{"Blaaaa"}};
SetAttributes[dran, HoldFirst]
dran[h_] := AppendTo[h, {"Hahaha"}]
dran[p]
```

> {{"Blaaaa"}, {"Hahaha"}}

note that `p` itself has been changed.

```
p
```

> {{"Blaaaa"}, {"Hahaha"}}

note if you try to use this function with a literal argument you come back to the same issue:

```
dran[{{"xyz"}}]
```

> {{"xyz"}} is not a variable with a value, so its value cannot be changed

Probably its better to use plain `Append`, which will work without `HoldFirst` and leaves the input argument unchanged.

```
p = {{"Blaaaa"}};
dran[h_] := Append[h, {"Hahaha"}]
dran[p]
p
```

> {{"Blaaaa"}, {"Hahaha"}}
>
> {{"Blaaaa"}}

Comment: Ahh thank you very much, well in fact I want to change my input argument :D I will give this a try, thanks so much :)

Comment: I'd still recommend using the `Append` form and do `p=dran[p]` if you want `p` to be changed, but that's really a matter of style/preference.